# How to write full api test case in camel blueprint

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

How do we write a test case using `CamelBlueprintTestSupport` for a soap service?
My requirement is to hit individual routes so that I can create test cases for each operations.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation to for writing tests using CamelBlueprintTestSupport? In brief, instantiate the blueprint, start your routes, then inject a message to your route to start the processing.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti can I get a sample code?